# Why is the guest account missing/broken in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

In older versions of Windows and even in Windows 10 previews you could enable the built-in guest account in control panel

> Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts\Manage Accounts

[image: available guest account in older Windows versions]

In Windows 10, the `Guest` entry is missing.

Using `Computer Management` or `net user` you can still enable the guest account, but even then it doesn't show up on the logon screen.

In the Local Security Policy `secpol.msc`:

> Local Policies - User Rights Assignment - Deny log on locally

we can see `guest` listed, this wasn't the case in older versions of Windows.

After removing `guest` from that policy, it is listed on the logon screen and we can using it to log on.

However, the whole Explorer shell is crashing and restarting constantly. The desktop is blinking and you can't click anything.

So the guest account is totally broken.

There is a [question on answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/built-in-guest-account-errors/636d8535-49ec-4312-b03c-5b05cf5827ea) about this showing that some code was quickly added to the control panel to not show the guest account. So Microsoft does know about the problem.

While I don't really expect anybody to know what they've done to break this, at least this explains why the guest account is currently not listed.

Comment: I'm sure MS is working on a fix or they are never going to enable it, i assume they want people to use Microsoft accounts to sign in. imho W10 is still in beta even thought it is RTM. There is no way anyone can answer your questions since we are not MS insiders.

Comment: @Moab - So would it be better to just ask `Why is there no guest account in Windows 10` and then answer it: `Because it is broken`? And move the details into the answer?

Comment: We don't know if it is "broken" or Microsoft is going to eliminate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's up with guest accounts in Windows 10? Can I have one?](https://superuser.com/questions/1526554/whats-up-with-guest-accounts-in-windows-10-can-i-have-one)

Answer (score 25):

The Guest account is disabled by default in Windows 10. However, guest is a reserved word, so you should create a new account under a different name (such as "Visitor") then put it in the guests localgroup:

1. Open command prompt window as administrator
2. `net user Visitor /add /active yes`
3. `net user Visitor *`
4. When asked to set a password just press Enter twice (blank password).
5. `net localgroup users Visitor /delete`
6. `net localgroup guests Visitor /add`

You will have a Visitor (aka guest) account bestowed with all the powers of a normal guest account.

-- edit --
If you get the "System error 1376 has occurred." error, run: `net localgroup` and see what is the real name of the *users* and *guests* groups.
In german Windows (even after system language change) it is:
`net localgroup Benutzer Visitor /delete` and `net localgroup Gäste Visitor /add`

Comment: From a deleted answer by [Erik](http://superuser.com/users/535380/erik): it seems some parameters may need to be translated for localized versions. Like `gebruikers` and `gasten` for Dutch in `net localgroup gebruikers visitor /delete` and `net localgroup gasten visitor /add`.

Comment: After the user logs out from the  User Visitor Account will everything be deleted just like it was before in a Guest Account ?

Comment: I get an error message: user profile cannot be loaded

Comment: Note that you can change the "Display Name" for the account created as above, to "Guest" or whatever else you want. So from all outward appearances, it can be made to look just like the built-in Guest account. It still won't be exactly like the built-in Guest account though (user settings, files, etc. are preserved)

Comment: This method does not create a Guest account like the one from Windows 7 or Windows 8. It creates only a standard user account, that is named Visitor. If you read the description of the Guests group in Windows 10, it says: “Guests have the same access as members of the Users group by default, except for the Guest account which is further restricted.” Since Guest is a reserved account and it doesn't work, your Visitor is only a Standard Local User account.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the Guest account has been removed by Microsoft [since build 10159](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2943718/microsoft-windows/windows-10-build-10159-loses-the-windows-guest-account.html), in July 2015. Microsoft has not provided any context for this change and it's clear that this feature is not coming back any time soon. 
A big problem is that many websites and forums share several methods for enabling the Guest account and all of them don't work. No matter what you do, you might see a Guest account entry but you can never use it and you will only brake your installation of Windows 10.
Because of that, it is best that users disable the dummy Guest accounts that they have enabled, using this command in the Command Prompt: `net user guest /active:no`
I have documented this issue and its implications in article, to help users who got in trouble by trying to enable the Guest account. You can find it here:
[You can't enable the Guest account in Windows 10. Stop trying!](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/you-cant-enable-guest-account-windows-10-stop-trying)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your article about this issue. But you are just confirming my statement that the guest account is broken, you don't provide and answer to my question why that is. This should be a comment.

Comment: The Professional 's answer worked for me.

Comment: @Corporate-Geek - I believe your article is incorrect in that it's not that the guest account cannot be enabled, but that it has been relegated to only be used on shared computers. I'd like to know if you disagree with what I've said about this at https://superuser.com/questions/1526554/what-up-with-guest-accounts-in-windows-10-can-i-have-one/#1526555 .

Answer (score 1):

The guest account is neither missing nor broken. As of Windows 10 v 1607, the guest account became part of the configuration of “shared PC mode.” It is no longer suitable for use on a standalone computer. So for the owner of a standalone Windows 10 computer, it might as well be missing or broken, because it can't be used. For more details, see the [answer to *What's up with guest accounts in Windows 10? Can I have one?*](https://superuser.com/questions/1526554/whats-up-with-guest-accounts-in-windows-10-can-i-have-one/#1526555)

Comment: Finally! That sheds some light! Thank you for your research!