# Is Guest user account supported under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, guest-account

I was not able to find a way to create a `built-in Guest` user account under Windows 10 using their new Control Panel, so I resorted to adding it manually via the `Computer Management` snap-in:

[image]

After which it started appearing in the `User switcher`:

[image]

But if I click it to switch to it, Windows kicks me out into the login screen:

[image]

and nothing happens. (Note that the `Guest` account is no longer shown here.)

I also checked the event log and the only record it has about this event is under Local -> Windows Logs -> Application:

> The winlogon notification subscriber  was unavailable to
>   handle a notification event.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the other methods in [4 Ways to Enable and Disable Built-in Guest on Windows 10](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-enable-and-disable-built-in-guest-on-windows-10.html)

Comment: Workaround here to create a "visitor" account with with all the powers of a normal guest account. [Why is the guest account missing/broken in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/a/979836)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yeah, that's what I observed. I literally managed to hang up Explorer in that blinking state like he describes there. I had to literally do the power button reboot to fix it. I can't believe how buggy Windows 10 is. I hope they fix it soon.