# I created a guest account on windows 10 but unable to sign in,why?

Tags: windows, windows-10, guest-account

i have been able to create a guest account on windows 10, 
however i do not see the user name when i restart my computer, 
i see the guest account when i select switch user, yet when i select the username, nothing happens, how i can i sign in to my new guest account?

I have tried removing the account and creating another one still, i have been able to create guest account on 2 other PC's and they both work fine.
i am not sure what is with this, i am using hp m6 x365, windows pro.

Answer (score 2):

We should enable the guest account, and set the following settings:

Firstly,enable Guest account in **Local Users and Groups**

Step 1: In the **Start** menu or taskbar search box, type **Lusrmgr.msc** and then press Enter key to open **Local Users and Groups**.

Step 2: Here, on the left-side, under **Local Users and Groups (local)**, click **Users**.

Step 3: Next, in the middle pane, double-click on **Users** to view all user accounts on our Windows 10.

Step 4: Right-click the **Guest** and then click **Properties** or double-click on Guest to open its properties.

Step 5: To enable the Guest account, under the **General** tab, uncheck the option titled **Account is disabled**. In the full name field, type in a name for the account if you wish to have a different name for the account, and then click **Apply** button to enable the guest account.

[image]

Secondly, enable Guest account via Group Policy

Step 1: Open **Group Policy Editor**, by typing Edit Group Policy in the Start or taskbar search box and then pressing Enter key.

Step 2: In the **Group Policy Editor**, navigate to the following policy:
**Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options.**

Step 3: On the right-side, look for the policy labelled **Accounts: Guest account status** and double-click on the same to open its properties.

Step 4: Select **Enabled** option and then click **Apply** button to turn on the Guest account in Windows 10.

[image]

Thirdly, set "**Deny log on locally**" via Group Policy

Step 1: In the **Group Policy Editor**, navigate to the following policy:
**Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment.**

Step 2: On the right-side, look for the policy labelled **Deny log on locally** and double-click on the same to open its properties.

Step 3: Click **Guest** option and then click **Remove** button.

Step 4: Then click"**Apply**" and "**OK**".

[image]

Comment: Is this procedure safe to use? The following article says that it will seriously mess up my computer: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/you-cant-enable-guest-account-windows-10-stop-trying

Comment: @NewSites tested it on my pc, win 10 pro version 1709, build 16299.967 and it for sure didn't work here. It does enable the guest account and lets you select it when signing in, but actually trying to log in with it causes a ton of issues. First login got stuck in a "preparing windows" loop, and after a forced reboot it auto-logged in on the guest account and got stuck on a black screen with some periodic shell host error popups. CTRL+ALT+DEL to sign out worked, fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll add as an answer. From [another similar question](https://superuser.com/q/957676/826520):

> It seems that the Guest account has been removed by Microsoft [since
> build 10159](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2943718/microsoft-windows/windows-10-build-10159-loses-the-windows-guest-account.html), in July 2015. Microsoft has not provided any context
> for this change and it's clear that this feature is not coming back
> any time soon.  A big problem is that many websites and forums share
> several methods for enabling the Guest account and all of them don't
> work. No matter what you do, you might see a Guest account entry but
> you can never use it and you will only brake your installation of
> Windows 10. Because of that, it is best that users disable the dummy
> Guest accounts that they have enabled, using this command in the
> Command Prompt: `net user guest /active:no` I have documented this
> issue and its implications in article, to help users who got in
> trouble by trying to enable the Guest account. You can find it here:
> [You can't enable the Guest account in Windows 10. Stop trying!](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/you-cant-enable-guest-account-windows-10-stop-trying)

> The Guest account is disabled by default in Windows 10. However, guest
> is a reserved word, so you should create a new account under a
> different name (such as "Visitor") then put it in the guests
> localgroup:
>
> 1. Open command prompt window as administrator
> 2. `net user Visitor /add /active yes`
> 3. `net user Visitor *`
> 4. When asked to set a password just press Enter twice (blank password).
> 5. `net localgroup users Visitor /delete`
> 6. `net localgroup guests Visitor /add`
>
> You will have a Visitor (aka guest) account bestowed with all the
> powers of a normal guest account.
>
> -- edit --
>  If you get the "System error 1376 has occurred." error, run: `net localgroup` and see what is the real name
> of the *users* and *guests* groups.
> In german Windows (even after
> system language change) it is:
>  `net localgroup Benutzer
> Visitor /delete` and `net localgroup Gäste Visitor
> /add`